# NFC Error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nfc

I was about to make a program that reads NFC cards via NFC reader.

when I execute my program i get the following errros...

```
/home/dotmark/Desktop/nfc2/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
        ^

Error: libnfc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (/home/dotmark/Desktop/nfc2/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dotmark/Desktop/nfc2/node_modules/nfc/index.js:1:95)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
```

My script for loading nfc libraries is as follows...

```
var nfc  = require('nfc').nfc
  , util = require('util')
  ;

console.log('nfc.version(): ' + util.inspect(nfc.version(), { depth: null }));
    // { name: 'libfnc', version: '1.7.0' }

console.log('nfc.scan(): ' + util.inspect(nfc.scan(), { depth: null }));
```

Any help would be really great..

Comment: have you installed libnfc and libusb-dev - which nfc reader do you have?

Comment: yes ive installed them.. Ive  a NFC reader of Advanced Card systems